# Seeking Australian Irrigation Boundaries?

Tags: data, australia, boundaries

Does anyone know of a source for Irrigation district boundaries in Australia, specifically NSW?

Comment: For open data, even spatial, I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

[This data source](https://data.gov.au/dataset/australian-irrigation-areas-vector-version-1a-national-land-and-water-resources-audit) (from the Australian Bureau of Agriculture and Resource Economics and Sciences) includes irrigation areas for most of Australia.